# Compute maximize of $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5$

Tags: inequality, algorithms

For $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9$ are non-negative integer number and satisfied:

$\begin{align*} a_1+a_3-a_6=K_1\\ a_2+a_4-a_8=K_2\\ a_3+a_4+2a_5+a_6+a_8=K_3\\ a_4+a_5+a_6+a_8+a_9=K_4\\ a_3+a_5+a_6+a_7+a_8=K_5\\ a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_7+a_9=K_6 \end{align*}$

- With $K_1,K_2,K_3,K_4,K_5,K_6,(K_i\in \mathbb{Z})$ are given and  $-1000\le K_1,K_2,K_3\le 1000$ and $0\le K_4,K_4,K_6\le 1000$.

+Find maximize of $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7+a_8+a_9$.

> > This is my try:
> >     After a few transformations, I get: $a_6+a_7+a_8+a_9=\frac{K_4+K_5+K_6-(K_1+K_2+K_3)}{2}$.

So, now I just need compute the maximize of $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5$. But i can't do it!

Comment: It is impossible to write $S:=a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5$ in terms of $K_1,K_2,\ldots,K_6$.  Note that $K_6=K_1+K_2-K_3+K_4+K_5$ (is there a typo somewhere, or maybe a missing piece of information?), so you can ignore $K_6$.  If there exists a linear combination of $K_1,K_2,\ldots,K_5$ that equals $S$, by balancing the coefficients of $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_7$, it must take the form $S=K_1+K_2+\lambda K_3+\mu K_4$ for some $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, but balancing the coefficients of $a_3$ and $a_4$ yields $\lambda=0$ and $\mu=0$.   However, $$K_1+K_2=a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4-a_6-a_8\neq S\,.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_9$ are nonnegative inegers, it is necessary that $$0\leq K_3\leq \min\{K_1+K_2+2K_4,K_1+K_2+2K_5,K_1+2K_4,K_2+2K_5,K_4+K_5\}\,,$$ $$K_1+\min\{K_3,K_4,K_5\}\geq 0\,,$$ $$K_2+\min\{K_3,K_4,K_5\}\geq 0\,,$$ and $$K_1+K_2+\min\{K_3,K_4,K_5\}\geq 0\,.$$  We shall assume these inequalities implicitly throughout this answer.  Because $$K_6=K_1+K_2-K_3+K_4+K_5\,,$$ we can ignore $K_6$ for the most part except that the constraints $0\leq K_6\leq 1000$ means
$$0\leq K_1+K_2-K_3+K_4+K_5\leq 1000\,.$$
However, this is just another constraint on the parameters $K_1$, $K_2$, $K_3$, $K_4$, and $K_5$.

We have
$$F:=\sum_{i=1}^9\,a_i\leq a_1+a_2+2a_3+2a_4+2a_5+a_6+a_7+a_8+a_9=K_1+K_2+K_4+K_5\,.$$
The equality holds if and only if $a_3=a_4=a_5=0$.  This implies
$$a_1-a_6=K_1\,,$$
$$a_2-a_8=K_2\,,$$
$$a_6+a_8=K_3\,,$$
$$a_6+a_8+a_9=K_4\,,$$ and
$$a_6+a_7+a_8=K_5\,.$$
Thus, $a_9=K_4-K_3$, $a_8=K_3-a_6$, $a_7=K_5-K_3$, $a_2=K_2+K_3-a_6$ and $a_1=K_1+a_6$.  This is possible iff $K_3\leq \min\{K_4,K_5\}$, where one solution is $$\begin{align}\big(a_1&,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9\big)\\&=\small\big(K_1+\min\{K_2+K_3,K_3\},K_2+K_3-\min\{K_2+K_3,K_3\},0,0,0,\min\{K_2+K_3,K_3\},K_5-K_3,K_3-\min\{K_2+K_3,K_3\},K_4-K_3\big)\,.\end{align}$$

Now we investigate the case $K_3>\min\{K_4,K_5\}$.  Since we have $K_3\leq K_4+K_5$, there are three situations: $$K_4=\min\{K_3,K_4,K_5\}\text{ or }K_5=\min\{K_3,K_4,K_5\}\,.$$

Observe that
$$F\leq a_1+a_2+a_3+2a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7+a_8+2a_9= K_1+K_2-K_3+2K_4+K_5$$
where the equality occurs iff $a_4=a_9=0$.  If $K_4\leq K_5<K_3$, then we may take 
$a_4=a_7=a_9=0$, and get a solution
$$\begin{align}\big(a_1&,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9\big)\\&=\small\big(K_1+K_4-K_5+\max\{0,-K_1-K_4+K_5\},K_2-K_3+K_4+K_5-\max\{0,-K_1-K_4+K_5\},K_5-K_4,0,K_3-K_5,\max\{0,-K_1-K_4+K_5\},0,-K_3+K_4+K_5-\max\{0,-K_1-K_4+K_5\},0\big)\,.\end{align}$$ 
If $K_4<K_3\leq K_5$, then we may take $a_4=a_5=a_9=0$, and get a solution
$$\begin{align}\big(a_1&,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9\big)\\&=\small\big(K_1-K_3+K_4+\max\{0,-K_1+K_3-K_4\},0,K_2+K_4-\max\{0,-K_1+K_3-K_4\},K_3-K_4,0,0,\max\{0,-K_1+K_3-K_4\},K_5-K_3,K_4-\max\{0,-K_1+K_3-K_4\},0\big)\,.\end{align}$$

Next, observe that
$$F\leq a_1+a_2+2a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+2a_7+a_8+a_9= K_1+K_2-K_3+K_4+2K_5$$
where the equality occurs iff $a_3=a_7=0$.  If $K_5=\min\{K_3,K_4,K_5\}$, then we may take $a_3=a_5=a_7=0$, and get a solution
$$\begin{align}\big(a_1&,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9\big)\\&=\small\big(K_1+K_5-\max\{0,-K_2+K_3-K_5\},K_2-K_3+K_5+\max\{0,-K_2+K_3-K_5\},0,K_3-K_5,0,K_5-\max\{0,-K_2+K_3-K_5\},0,\max\{0,-K_2+K_3-K_5\},K_4-K_5\big)\,.\end{align}$$

In conclusion, the maximum value of $F$ is
$$F_\text{max}=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
K_1+K_2+K_4+K_5&\text{if }K_3=\min\{K_3,K_4,K_5\}\,,\\
K_1+K_2-K_3+2K_4+K_5&\text{if }K_4=\min\{K_3,K_4,K_5\}\,,\\
K_1+K_2-K_3+K_4+2K_5&\text{if }K_5=\min\{K_3,K_4,K_5\}\,.
\end{array}
\right.$$

---

Here, we are determining the minimum possible value of $F$.  Note that
$$F\geq a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_7+a_9=K_1+K_2-K_3+K_4+K_5\,,$$
where the equality case happens when $a_5=a_6=a_8=0$.  That is,
$$a_1+a_3=K_1$$
$$a_2+a_4=K_2$$
$$a_3+a_4=K_3$$
$$a_4+a_9=K_4$$
and
$$a_3+a_7=K_5$$
This requires $K_1\geq 0$, $K_2\geq 0$, and $K_3\leq \min\{K_1+K_2,K_1+K_4,K_2+K_5,K_4+K_5\}$. 
 A solution is
$$\begin{align}\big(a_1&,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9\big)\\&=\small\big(K_1-\min\{K_1,K_3,K_5\},K_2-K_3+\min\{K_1,K_3,K_5\},\min\{K_1,K_3,K_5\},K_3-\min\{K_1,K_3,K_5\},0,0,K_5-\min\{K_1,K_3,K_5\},0,K_4-K_3+\min\{K_1,K_3,K_5\}\big)\,.\end{align}$$
There are other cases to deal with but I am exhausted.

Comment: First of all, I am really thank for your help. What do you think when the requirement is: Compute minimize of $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5$?

Comment: You can write $S:=a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5$ as $S=F+K_3-K_4-K_5$.   So, in one case (see the edit), you see that the minimum value of $S$ is $K_1+K_2$.

Comment: So, I'm thank you very much!!! I'have understood this problem!

Comment: Great you are back! :)

Comment: @Aqua  I was very busy.  I have a small break now, but will disappear again soon.  Thanks for thinking of me :D.  I will show up here from time to time, though.

Comment: :( ..............................